# How to make links in Sparkle release notes open default browser?

Tags: html, xml, xcode, macos, sparkle

I am using Sparkle for updates in a macOS app, and pass release notes in the  appcast.xml tag:

`<sparkle:releaseNotesLink>https://example.com/release-notes.html</sparkle:releaseNotesLink>`

The release notes contain HTML, which Sparkle displays, and link to more information about the release on my website, for example:

`<p>This is our latest update. <a href="https://example.com/learn-more/" target="_blank">Learn more</a></p>`

But when I click on the link, nothing happens. I would expect it to open the default system browser, like other applications that use Sparkle do when they include links in their release notes.

Any advice on how to get links working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the

```html
"target=_blank"
```

and that will fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why it doesn’t work with `target`?